# Propagator of massive spin-1 particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator

I am currently working on an exercise where I need to derive the propagator, in momentum space, of a massive spin-1 particle. The image included is the solution to it, and I am having trouble understanding parts of it.
[image: propagatorexercise]
Namely, how do they go from eq. (80) to eq. (81)?

As I see it, eq. (80) is summed over $\mu$ and $\nu$ and is therefore a scalar equation. How can we extract information about the terms in the sum?

My second problem is that eq. (86) looks wrong, as the left part should be a scalar again, and the right part still has the uncontracted indices. Technically this is no problem, but something seems fishy to me.

It appears I don't really understand how they go from the tensorial equations to scalar ones, the rest of the solution is ok for me.

Comment: Sloppy book; which one is it? (86) is spectacularly malformed.

Comment: Hint: multiply (85) by $g_{\mu\kappa}$ and see what you get, after renaming your indices.

Comment: Which book was this?

Comment: Fortunately it's not a book, these are the exercise sheets I get every week.

Comment: You know what, there are dozens of QFT texts online that have been proof-read more responsibly, and from which you can learn. Your class should ask the instructor to take responsibility for his sloppy handouts which generate such confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the Fourier transform of both sides of equation $80$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, the right hand side will become $\delta^{(4)}(k_1-k_2)$, the left hand side will pick up a $\delta^{(4)}(k_1-k_2)\,\delta^{(4)}(k_1-q)$. After evaluating the $q$ integral on the left hand side you can replace $k_1$ with $q$ and drop the delta functions on both sides.

There is, technically, a mistake in the very first equation that gets corrected in the transition to $81$. Equation $78$ should read something like
$$\left[g^{\mu\nu}\left(\Box + M^2\right) - \partial^\mu\partial^\nu\right]G^F_{\nu\lambda} = i\delta^{4}(x-y)\,\delta^\mu_{\hphantom{\mu}\lambda}.$$
There is a way to argue the opening up of the summation that takes place in the initial work, I'm sure, I just can't think of how it's done right now.

Comment: There isn't much to argue: you wrote the correct Green's function of the bracket operator.

Comment: If this is the correct definition of the green's function then this already makes a lot more sense. However,  I've found something similar to eq. (78) (without mass, for the photon) in my script. The propagator is defined as the green's function of the wave operator, however it seems I don't really know how to extend this definition to a propagator tensor.. Is there a logical explanation it should be done in the way you wrote it down? Or does it amount to the same thing as in eq. (78)(since you said technically)?

Comment: Normally, the propagator is the expectation value of suitable arrangements of two EM fields (vector potentials $A^\mu$), each obeying the tensorial wave equation, and the green's function is thus tensor.... think of the inverse of a matrix. It is easy to contract tensor indices to get a scalar, but reconstructing a tensor out of its trace is a bit much, isn't it?

Comment: Propagator and Green's function aren't quite 100% interchangeable, @CosmosZachos. The propagator is defined by $\langle A^\mu(x)\, A^\nu(y)\rangle$, as you stated. The Green's function comes from finding a formal inverse of the classical equations of motion - equivalent to finding the response of the field to a point-like impulse given some boundary conditions. That's how you know the equation should be tensorial here, TimLorenzoFleischmann, when finding an inverse the RHS needs to be a complete identity element.

Comment: The difference being that propagators generally have to be symmetric under interchange (transpose of Lorentz indices and space-time coordinates) and don't have to obey the same sort of causality constraints, whilst Green's functions can assume more forms, depending  on the type of problem being solved: initial conditions (retarded), final conditions (advanced), boundary conditions (e.g. when initial and final fields are fixed, but not momenta), etc.